# SignalR and Query Notifications in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, signalr, query-notifications

I'm new in signalr, and reading and surfing the net I found this incredible (I think) tutorial 
http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency.
But I have a problem, when I run the statement `GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO "Domain\ASPNET"` replacing `Domain\ASPNET` with my Windows credentials, the SQL management threw this error:

`Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.`

There is something wrong in my procedure? There is any other way to implement this push from the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message you posted, I'd guess you are logged into SQL Manager using the same credentials you are attempting to `GRANT` to.

Comment: Yes! In that case what should I do?

Comment: Either log into SQL Manager as `sa` to do this work or create a separate DB user account to grant these to.

Comment: Thanks you all!! that was the help I was needing.

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO YourUserName;
```

Use your login username insted of YourName